# C++ Emulating int main(int argc, char *argv[]) from node

Tags: c++, arrays, node.js, node-gyp

Basically I am working on integrating an existing C++ file with our javascript / node using their NAPI, functionality. I have it working on a test C++ file so I know I have the setup working. However on the actual C++ file it is designed to run from the command line with argc and argv from the command line. Basically I just need to invoke the main method in C++ from inside of my other function, which means there is no command line. So I have to pass in values for argc and argv. argc is just an int, that is easy enough, but argc is a char ** type, which from my research looks like it is an array of character arrays aka strings?

This is my current code at the bottom of my c++ file

```
void Init(Env env, Object exports, Object module) {
    exports.Set("main", Function::New(env, main(2,{"test","test2"})));
}
NODE_API_MODULE(addon, Init)
```

The argc value is working fine

I am trying to create a temporary / test value for argv to pass in but I am having an issue figuring out how to make an array of type char ** with my values.

Comment: That is essentially what I am trying to figure out. if I try "test test" this is what I get  "note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const char [11]' to 'char **' for 2nd argument
int main(int argc, char *argv[])"

Comment: Nah that was a dumb suggestion of mine. I'm seeing that you might be able to declare `napi_value argv[2]` and then push items to that array, however I haven't used it. I might suggest trying `main(2,["test1","test2"])` or perhaps `main(2,&["test1","test2"])`.

Comment: Important fun fact: Calling `main` from within a program is undefined behaviour. Weird smurf could happen. You are better off moving the code in `main` to another function with the same parameters and having `main` and your simulation call this other function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`argv` is an array of pointers to strings (actually, NUL-terminated character arrays), where element 0 is the name of the program, elements 1 ... `argc-1` are the program arguments, and element `argc` must be `NULL`<sup>1</sup>.

There's no array literal in C++, so you have to create explicitly an array variable to pass it to a function. Even worse, `main` is allowed to modify the passed arguments, so you cannot even build an array of string literals, as they are read only; thus, you have to explicitly allocate read/write space for each argument. A barebones solution can be to have single buffers for each argument and build the pointer array out of them:

```
char argv0[] = "test_program";
char argv1[] = "arg1";
char argv2[] = "arg2";
char *argv[] = {argv0, argv1, argv2, NULL};
main(3, argv);
```

A more flexible one (especially if you have to build your arguments dynamically) can be to use an `std::vector<std::string>`:

```
std::vector<std::string> args = { "test_program", "arg1", "arg2" };
// ... here you may add other arguments dynamically...
args.push_back("arg3"); // whatever
// build the pointers array
std::vector<char *> argv;
for(std::string &s: args) argv.push_back(&s[0]);
argv.push_back(NULL);
main(argv.size()-1, argv.data());
```

---

Now, coming to your code:

```
void Init(Env env, Object exports, Object module) {
    exports.Set("main", Function::New(env, main(2,{"test","test2"})));
}
NODE_API_MODULE(addon, Init)
```

besides the fact that you cannot build `argv` to pass to `main` like that, you are trying to *invoke* `main` and pass its result as second argument to `Function::New`, while `Function::New` [wants some callable type](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api/blob/master/napi.h#L781) (e.g. a function pointer) to register as handler for the export named `main`! Copying from the `Function::New` documentation:

> ```
> /// Callable must implement operator() accepting a const CallbackInfo&
> /// and return either void or Value.
> ```

So, as a simple example, you could export your main as a parameterless JS function that returns nothing (`undefined`, I guess?) by registering a callback like this:

```
void MainCallback(const CallbackInfo& info) {
    char argv0[] = "test_program";
    char argv1[] = "arg1";
    char argv2[] = "arg2";
    char *argv[] = {argv0, argv1, argv2, NULL};
    main(3, argv);
}

void Init(Env env, Object exports, Object module) {
    exports.Set("main", Function::New(env, MainCallback));
}
NODE_API_MODULE(addon, Init)
```

Finally, as others said, technically in C++ `main` is somewhat magic - it's undefined behavior to invoke it from inside the program; in practice, on any platform that I know of that can also run node.js, `main` is a perfectly regular function that happens to be invoked by the C runtime at startup, so I don't think that this will cause you any problem.

---

#### Notes

1. So, you could say it's a NULL-terminated array of NUL-terminated character arrays. Notice that here `NULL` = null pointer; NUL = string terminator, i.e. `'\0'`.

Comment: “where the first value is the name of the program, the second to (`argc`-1)th are the program arguments, and the `argc`th must be `NULL`.”

You’re mixing 0- and 1-based indexing there. `argv[0]` must be the program name and `argv[argc]` must be `NULL`. If you call `argv[0]` the “first” element, then `argv[argc]` is the (`argc`+1)th element. I’d avoid ordinals completely and just say “element 0”, “elements 1 through `argc`-1”, and “element number `argc`”.

Comment: @DanielH: yep; I rephrased a bit, always specifying explicitly both the English ordinal and the C array index, but probably just writing indexes as you say is less confusing; fixing...